# How to use mongodb embedded schema in java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

I am stuck here, i want to keep address of user as embedded document . But there,it is creating another table of address in database. so i want one table "user" and inside it,i want my embedded document like "address". what will be the domain design of user ?.

Now,my user domain is

```
class User{
String name;
Address adress;
}
```

My address domain is

```
class Address{
   String city;
}
```

My controller is

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class UserController {
public Map<String, Object> saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userService.saveUser(user);
        return ResponseHandler.generateResponse("User registerted successfully", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED, false, null);
    }

}
```

My service is

```
public void saveUser(User user){
        Address a = new Address();
        a.setCity("delhi");
User user = new User();
user.setAddress(a);
        userDao.save(user);
    }
```

I want result is in database,not table of address separately.i am using spring-data-mongotemplate for this.how can i do this ?

```
user{

  address:[{},{}] // multiple address could be
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
@Document
public class User {
    private String name;
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

    // ctr, getters, setters...

    public static class Address {
        private String city;

        public Address(String city) { 
            this.city = city;
        }

        // getters, setters...
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
User.Address address = new User.Address("NY");
user.setAddress(address);
mongoTemplate.save(user);
```

Basically, parsing User from json should work:

```
{ name : "userName", addresses : [ { city : 'NY' } ] }
```

And you don't have to embed Address class into User class. Just add @Document on User and ebmed Address object in it.

Comment: thanku for quik response,but id is not created of address object,it is null,so how to do it ?

Comment: Just create field named "id", with type org.bson.types.ObjectId and annotate in with @Id annotation (org.springframework.data.annotation.Id). Do it both for User and Address

Comment: actually i have a id in common class ,and user and address extends that class,so in database user document have a id and but address document haven't id,showing null

Comment: Try address.setId(ObjectId.get());

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Document` annotation in user, and both must implements `Serializable`.

Regards.